# Adding different values in a single cell

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine we have a table as:

```
AAA BBB 123
AAA BBB 456
AAA BBB 789
```

How can i see these three in a single row as:

AAA BBB 123-456-789 (multiple cells are added to a single cell using a delimiter)

Cheers.

Comment: search for group_concat workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the answer [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5981860/305207):

```
WITH X AS 
(
    SELECT 'AAA' AS A, 'BBB' AS B, 123 AS C
    UNION
    SELECT 'AAA' AS A, 'BBB' AS B, 456 AS C
    UNION
    SELECT 'AAA' AS A, 'BBB' AS B, 789 AS C
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    X.A,
    X.B,
    STUFF((SELECT '-' + CAST(C AS VARCHAR(3)) FROM X FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    X
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      a VARCHAR(10)
    , b VARCHAR(10)
    , c INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp (a, b, c)
VALUES 
    ('AAA', 'BBB', 123),
    ('AAA', 'BBB', 456),
    ('AAA', 'BBB', 789)

SELECT t.a + ' ' + t.b + STUFF((
    SELECT '-' + CAST(c AS VARCHAR(10))
    FROM @temp t2
    WHERE t2.a = t.a
        AND t2.b = t.b
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, ' ')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT a, b 
    FROM @temp
) t
```

**Output:**

```
AAA BBB 123-456-789
```